# When I scroll down a bit I want it to scroll below the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, revolution-slider

I am trying to make a slider and when I scroll down I want it to jump into the content

I tried this but it doesn't feel smooth

```
var up = 0;
$(window).scroll(function()
{
 if ($(window).scrollTop()> 50 && up==0) 
 {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: ( 
($(".vc_custom_1449248739486").offset().top)-50) }, 500);
    up++;
 }
 if( $(window).scrollTop()<20)
 {
    up=0;
 }
});
```

I want to scroll and  to slide it down to the content.

You can check the code and inspect it here:
http://junglelodge.nevadastudios.com/

Comment: you need to include the rest of the code, maybe in a codepen so we can see what's going on

Comment: Just added the website you can inspect it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for smooth scrolling:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: document.querySelector(".vc_custom_1449248739486").offsetTop - 50, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Comment: Still looks shaky I think the error is that I don't disable the mouse scroll while I am scrolling down